# Flutter Web render text elements to HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is it possible to render text elements ( widgets ) as HTML, so that when looking at the source code of the website I have h1,h2,p... tags? Having everything as a part of canvas poses a big issue for Google crawlers.
Thanks!